# Is Babun shell on Windows portable?

Tags: windows, command-line

Can I install babun shell with /t switch and point to usb drive to get portable environment?

Comment: It sounds like you think it might. Have you tried it? What did that do?

Comment: I didnt try that yet.I dont want to install something on usb and something on C drive, registry...It have install with /t switch in instructions.txt to change default install location